# batch script that will install an application from a dynamic drive letter

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that auto executes an installation (MSI, MSP, or EXE) from USB drive.

I have Microsoft Office 2013 loaded on a flash drive, when I plug this into any computer, I want my batch file to auto execute and install the application from whatever drive letter mapping the OS gives the USB drive

Here is my current path to the installation `%drive%\Office2013\32bit`

Here is my code:

```
START /WAIT setup.exe /adminfile ofc13-pp32-ca.MSP
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Modern Windows do not execute random scripts on USB drivers automatically. If you want something close to it, you can create [`autorun.inf`](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/autolaunch-apps-usb-stick-windows/) file in the USB drive root and have it give you an option to run your batch file.